# how can i customize button like this..?

Tags: css, button

A image I designed on Figma:

[image]

My attempt:

```css
.pagenumber {
  display: flex;
  width: 252.27px;
  height: 45px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 6.761954261954262% 0 0 37.680647534952171%;
}

button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

.no {
  width: 65.750981091687478%;
  padding: 0 12px 0 22.5px;
}

.numbers {
  background: #ffe400;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 45px;
  width: 45.24px;
}

.no a {
  color: black;
  font-family: Lobster;
  font-size: 187.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagenumber">

  <div class="arrowbtn">
    <button type="submit" onclick="history.back(-1)"><i class="fas fa-greater-than fa-flip-horizontal fa-2x" style="color: #ffe400;"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div class="no">
    <button class="numbers"><a href="">1</a></button>
    <button class="numbers"><a href="">2</a></button>
    <button class="numbers"><a href="">3</a></button>
  </div>

  <div class="arrowbtn">
    <button type="submit" method="get" action="/page2"><i class="fas fa-greater-than fa-2x" style="color: #ffe400;"></i></button>
  </div>

</div>
```

I wanna a page number button like this image but I don't know how to make space between 1,2,3 button. The space between the buttons is 15.08px. If you find some drawback from my code pls notice me.

Comment: Hi there. It would be helpful say where you are having difficulties whilst trying to reproduce the design, and what you have tried so far to overcome those difficulties and why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the flex properties to your **.no** class instead and update the width.

If you're just wanting a simple way to get spacing between your elements just set a desired **width** without using **calc** and **space-between** will do the rest.

If you're looking to get the exact spacing you desire then I recommend using **calc** to calculate what the width of the parent element should be to fit your required spacing.

*My calculation explained:*

- Multiply the width of the 3 number elements **(45.24px * 3)**
- Add that to the multiplication of the exact spacing you want between the number elements **(15.08px * 2)**, in this case multiplying the desired spacing by 2 since you have 3 elements and only require 2 spaces in between.

**Note that if you use the *calc* method you will have to update the calculation each time you update the number of elements you want to display.**

```css
.pagenumber {
  display: flex;
  width: 252.27px;
  height: 45px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 6.761954261954262% 0 0 37.680647534952171%;
}

button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

.no {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: calc(45.24px * 3 + 15.08px * 2);
  padding: 0 12px;
}

.numbers {
  background: #ffe400;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 45px;
  width: 45.24px;
}

.no a {
  color: black;
  font-family: Lobster;
  font-size: 187.5%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<div class="pagenumber">

  <div class="arrowbtn">
    <button type="submit" onclick="history.back(-1)"><i class="fas fa-greater-than fa-flip-horizontal fa-2x" style="color: #ffe400;"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div class="no">
    <button class="numbers"><a href="">1</a></button>
    <button class="numbers"><a href="">2</a></button>
    <button class="numbers"><a href="">3</a></button>
  </div>

  <div class="arrowbtn">
    <button type="submit" method="get" action="/page2"><i class="fas fa-greater-than fa-2x" style="color: #ffe400;"></i></button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="pagenumber">

  <div class="arrowbtn">
    <button type="submit" onclick="history.back(-1)"><i class="fas fa-greater-than fa-flip-horizontal fa-2x" style="color: #ffe400;"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div class="no">
    <button class="numbers"><a href="">1</a></button>
    <button class="numbers"><a href="">2</a></button>
    <button class="numbers"><a href="">3</a></button>
  </div>

  <div class="arrowbtn">
    <button type="submit" method="get" action="/page2"><i class="fas fa-greater-than fa-2x" style="color: #ffe400;"></i></button>
  </div>

</div>

<style>
  .pagenumber {
    display: flex;
    width: 252.27px;
    height: 45px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 6.761954261954262% 0 0 37.680647534952171%;
  }
  
  button {
    background: none;
    border: none;
  }
  
  .no {
    padding: 0 12px 0 22.5px;
  }
  
  .numbers {
    background: #ffe400;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    margin-right: 15.08px;
  }

  .no :nth-last-child(1) {
    margin-right: 0px;
  }
  
  .no a {
    color: black;
    font-family: Lobster;
    font-size: 187.5%;
  }
</style>
```

Remove the width on `no` and set `margin-right` on `numbers` will do.

Answer (score 0):

Hi to get space between your number button you just need to apply margin like margin: 0 5px or something on your number class and if you want to remove lines which is on number button apply text-decoration: none on anchor tag

like that...

```
<style type="text/css">
    .pagenumber {
      /*display: flex;*/
      /*width: 252.27px;*/
      height: 45px;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 6.761954261954262% 0 0 37.680647534952171%;
    }

    button {
      background: none;
      border: none;
    }

    .no {
      width: 65.750981091687478%;
      padding: 0 12px 0 22.5px;
    }

    .numbers {
      background: #ffe400;
      border-radius: 50%;
      height: 45px;
      width: 45.24px;
          margin: 0 5px;
    }

    .no a {
      color: black;
      font-family: Lobster;
      font-size: 187.5%;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
<div class="pagenumber">

  <div class="arrowbtn">
    <button type="submit" onclick="history.back(-1)"><i class="fas fa-greater-than fa-flip-horizontal fa-2x" style="color: #ffe400;"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div class="no">
    <button class=""><a href=""><</a></button>
    <button class="numbers"><a href="">1</a></button>
    <button class="numbers"><a href="">2</a></button>
    <button class="numbers"><a href="">3</a></button>
    <button class=""><a href="">></a></button>
  </div>

  <div class="arrowbtn">
    <button type="submit" method="get" action="/page2"><i class="fas fa-greater-than fa-2x" style="color: #ffe400;"></i></button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```css
button {background: yellow; border-radius:50%}
```

```html
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
```